# Query for schedule date comparison

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
account number(repeat) | schedule_due_date
---------------------- | -----------------
111                    | '01-FEB-2017'
111                    | '01-MAR-2017'
111                    | '01-APR-2017'
```

I want a SQL query which will give the account number if `schedule_due_date` is first or last.

If `sysdate` is `01-FEB-2017` then it should give the account number or if `sysdate` is `01-APR-2017` then it should give the account number.

But, if `sysdate` is `01-MAR-2017` then it should not give the account number.
Actually it should check for min date and max date with `sysdate` for all accounts and give results.

Comment: This seems perfectly straightforward. What are you finding so hard about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below one, (use a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` can solve this).

```
SELECT  account_number
FROM    table1
GROUP BY    account_number
HAVING  MAX(schedule_due_date) = sysdate
    OR  MIN(schedule_due_date) = sysdate
```

Comment: Probably want to truncate the SYSDATE to remove the time element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT  account_number
FROM    table1 
where schedule_due_date  = (select max(schedule_due_date) from table1 )
or schedule_due_date  = (select min(schedule_due_date) from table1 )
```